# getting version during preversion step

Tags: semantic-release

I am using a package called `babel-plugin-inline-package-json` to pull out my version number during my build step. Currently using semantic-release the package version is always 0.0.0 instead of the correct version number. I setup semantic-release to trigger a build using the npm `preversion` command. I was under the impression that by the time semantic-release triggered preversion it would already have the new version inserted into the package.json, but I keep getting 0.0.0 instead. What would be the correct way to pull out the version number so I can get it during my build step?

Comment: for what it's worth, you can find something describing your situation there: https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/caribou/docs/support/FAQ.md#how-can-i-use-a-npm-build-script-that-requires-the-packagejsons-version-. I however am looking at how to implement that in my flow, and it's hard to find examples I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

semantic-release doesn't trigger the npm `preversion` directly, it runs `npm version` then `npm publish`. The [npm hook scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description) (`preversion`, `postversion`, `prepack`, `postpack`, `prepublish`, `prepublishOnly`, `postpublish`, `prepare`) are triggered by `npm` itself.

As suggested by it's name the hook `preversion` run just before the version is updated. You need to use the `postversion` hook which run after the version is updated.

For more details see: [How can I use a npm build script that requires the package.json’s version ?](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/caribou/docs/support/FAQ.md#how-can-i-use-a-npm-build-script-that-requires-the-packagejsons-version-)